# Seeking high-resolution (at least 1 foot) imagery of California

Tags: data, imagery, united-states

Is there a national site or state site that will allow me to download High Res (1') aerial imagery of California?

I have tried [Cal-Atlas Download](http://www.atlas.ca.gov/download.html#/casil/imageryBaseMapsLandCover/imagery/naip) but they are at one meter. I have also tried [USGS Viewer](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/) and selecting by county, but when I do that it gets broken up into 100+ chunk images and only covers about 10% of the county.

The specifics of what I am looking for is California High Res aerial imagery (1') by counties. Mrsid would be ideal, but JPEG2000 is fine too. Mosaic would be ideal, but tiles are fine as well.

Comment: What is the area of interest you are after?

Comment: Check out USGS bulk data option, http://cumulus.cr.usgs.gov/bulk.php

Answer (score 1):

For those ArcGIS users out there, USDA-AFPO has a webmap service for the current national-level NAIP imagery. You can set it up as a "GIS Servers > Add ArcGIS Server" service in ArcCatalog. The URL is: http://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/services

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what USGS viewer you are referring to, however I am sure that earth explorer has 1 M gsd of JPG 2000 aerial imagery.  This is NAIP imagery that I am speaking of, however there are other data sets for you to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [National Map](http://nationalmap.gov/viewer.html), I don't know where you're looking in CA but I just zoomed around a bit and found 0.3m resolution aerials in the San Joaquin valley and in the Central Valley -Lower Sacramento River. Just navigate to the area you're interested in, click "Download Data" in the upper-right, and draw a bounding box. There also seems to be a set for Napa county. I doubt 1-foot imagery is available for the entirety of California though.

Answer (score 0):

I got 1ft/pixel images as tiled non-georeferenced images by using [GMapCatcher](https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/) - I'm looking for a way to use that for >fast< browsing, with arcgis explorer, either as an offline tiled dataset or by converting to mrsid: the GMapCatcher browser is great and lightweight, but we're looking for something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most orthoimagery at less than 1m resolution is purchased/licensed at a regional scale rather than statewide. You'd do best to either contact GIS or Planning staff at individual counties or contact a vendor such as Eagle Aerial or Pictometry. Also, you'll likely find there are few if any imagery at that resolution that is available at no cost.